# What is the tag "etymology" for?

Tags: discussion, tags

For me, it is very unclear. The tag can mean (and is used) in many cases:

- How a word is constructed (with the Esperanto rules of word construction)
- How a word evolved from the Unua libro to now
- How a word was elected by Zamenhof (or and the Akademio)
- How a word was in the languages before Esperanto (I am not sure if it suits this website. If Zamenhof elected a word from English, it is better to ask about the etymology of the English word in the English SE website. What is the etymology of this Esperanto word? Well, it is Zamenhof.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the above.

*Etymology* is simply asking about the origin of a word and how its meaning or construction may have changed over time. I wouldn't make it any more complicated than that.

It doesn't necessarily matter if those changes refer to an election or a natural evolution or simply fell into place based on the rules of construction. I may not even know; that's why I'm asking.

Just a note of caution about getting too pedantic with tags and getting more granular than is useful or warranted. Tags paint a broad swath. They were *not* meant to create a precise taxonomy that categorizes every possible question with academic precision. That will only make tagging more difficult, and useless to find or filter questions at all.